# rails 4 mongoid locales en.yml not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I am in the process of converting a rails application to run from sqlite to mongodb. So far so good but its not picking up my config/locales/en.yml settings:-

```
en:
  activerecord:
      models:
          access_ref: "Access Type"
          applicant_type_ref: "Applicant Type"
          applicant_custom_ref: "Applicant Custom Field"
          limit_ref: "Spending Limit Increment"
          tenure_ref: "Tenure Type"
          property_type_ref: "Property Type"
          property_custom_ref: "Property Custom Field"
```

What changes do I have to make so that the rails 4/mongoid environment picks the above settings please?

Many thanks

Comment: keep consistent indentation in your yaml files - two spaces is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution:

```
en:
  mongoid:
    attributes:
      model_name_here:
        access_ref: "Access Type"
        applicant_type_ref: "Applicant Type"
        applicant_custom_ref: "Applicant Custom Field"
        limit_ref: "Spending Limit Increment"
        tenure_ref: "Tenure Type"
        property_type_ref: "Property Type"
        property_custom_ref: "Property Custom Field"
```

This gist outlines how to craft custom errors as well: https://gist.github.com/lurkermike/1596505

Answer (score -1):

Try to change this activerecord: with mongoid: